# Sign in Native App after launching from Salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I am launching a native iOS app from Salesforce 1.  I am trying to see if there is a way to sign the user into the app with without having to login.  I am seeing if it is possible to pass information from SF1.  My biggest concern is of course the security issues with passing any information.  Can they both verify against the same URL and security token?